# How to replace a wordpress installation in root directory with another in a subdirectory?

Tags: directory, migration, installation, backup

Someone with a wordpress site in lets say www.thess.com asked me to change the theme, so i thought it would be safer to first create a second wordpress installation in lets say www.thess.com/welcome and then, after having moved all of the content to the new installation and calibrated the theme, move the new installation to the root directory.

So, i have reached to this point but i don't know what is the safest way to move www.thess.com/welcome to www.thess.com, apart from taking a backup of the files and database of the first installation.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the official codex page: [Moving WordPress within your site](http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress#Moving_WordPress_Within_Your_Site)

Go to `Admin Panel` -> `Settings` -> `General`.

Change `WordPress address (URI)`: (`www.thess.com/welcome` to `www.thess.com`)

Change `Site Address address (URL)`: (`www.thess.com/welcome` to `www.thess.com`)

Move your files from subdirectory to root. That's it.

Comment: Nice article! ..and how about the database? aren't there any necessary changes to link the database to the new directory?

Comment: No, no need to alter the database or its config if the contents are the same. You only will need to change database info when moving to a new server or importing a new database.